# What are sticker challenges and can I view my stickers?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-ii

Sometimes when I complete a challenge, the game says that I have completed a sticker challenge. This is accompanied but a UI box, with the EXP and usually an animated gif style image.

[image: Stickerbook Challenge]

I have checked the Gunsmith to see if they are weapon stickers, but they don't seem to be.

What are the Sticker book challenges and can I see the stickers I have collected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that these are not really 'Stickers' as in things that attach to your guns, but rather items that you can customise your operator with.

If you visit the Customize menu and visit the Calling Cards section, you can see the 'sticker' that was earnt as part of this challenge.

[image: The Price You Pay challenge]

It is in fact a calling card emblem.